# Automatic indentation with MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, autoindent, tex

How can I change the automatic indentation in MacVim?

My problem is that when editing a TeX file, every time I type, for example, `(`, vim decides to indent the line for me.

Here is a [video of my problem](http://whitecortex.net/~mikko/vimsekoilu.mp4). You can see it's infuriating.

I am on Mavericks, the about MacVim window shows version as

```
Snapshot 66, VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Dec 12 2012 16:22:25)  
MacOS X (unix) version  
Included patches: 1-754
```

I have installed pathogen, and the plugins used via that include `tabular`, `vim-slim`, `vim-colors-solarize`, and `vim-surround`. (Listing them all here because I don't know what is creating this behavior.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to find all the options that affect indenting is to open an options window with

```
:options
```

and then look at Section 15, "tabs and indenting".  Once you know which options are relevant, you can check their current values and which plugin is responsible with

```
:verbose set ai? si? cin? cink? inde? indk? ci? pi? lisp? lispw?
```

To actually disable a filetype-specific indentation; from the manual section 30.3:

> If you don't like the indenting for one specific type of file, this is
>   how you avoid it.  Create a file with just this one line: >
>
> ```
> :let b:did_indent = 1
> ```
>
> Now you need to write this in a file with a specific name:
>
> ```
> {directory}/indent/{filetype}.vim
> ```
>
> The {filetype} is the name of the file type, such as "cpp" or "java".

Comment: Got it; the latter command shows `indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e,[,(,{,),},]` from `vim/runtime/indent/tex.vim`. Do you know how to change it  locally, ie. in `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: Or better yet, how not to load that LaTeX-centric indentation plugin in the first place?

Comment: See `:help 30.3` in the users' manual.